# SP13 - Approve ListItem in source create new version(sync) in target label

Tags: list, splistitem, approval-process, variations, sync

I have two variation list - **source list** and **target list** and  have propagated list item from source to target list.

Where i approve new listitem in source list, **Variations Propagate List Items Job** create new draft version for this item in target list.

I do not want to create a draft version for this list item in my target list.

I want to do this only with button "Sync to target" in ribbon.

How to solve this problem, SharePoint specialists?

Comment: Any help, please?